# What are the 7 continents as per Hindu Cosmology?

Tags: cosmology, geography

According to Bhagavata Purana,

1. Agnidhara
2. Idhmajihva
3. Yajnabahu
4. Mahavira,
5. Hiranyareta,
6. Medhatithi,
7. Ghrtaprstha
8. Savana
9. Vitihotra
10. Kavi

These are the names of the Priyavrata. Seven (out of ten sons) who inherited the continents from Priyavrta. The three sons, Mahavira, Savana, and Kavi were avowed inveterate Bramacharins (celibate seekers of Bramah Vidya and god). (Priyavrata married Barhjismati, daughter of Visvakarma, the architect of the gods who gave him ten sons and a daughter Urjasvati.) Priyavrata had, by another spouse, three sons: Uttama, Tamasa, and Raivata who were in charge of three Manvantras, named after them.

I find difficult to understand this - thus, now he question from my side is - what are seven continents?

Comment: The basis they are renamed in modern world is matter related to science. On our site, [science in Q&A is off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/142/9125). It is appropriate on other scientific sites. Hence removed it. Please ask it on appropriate site.

Comment: The reason behind renaming I asked because I thought it would be bit easier to find out. That's why. Other than its for no reason I added it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [chapter 53 of Markandeya Purana](https://archive.org/stream/markandeyapurana/markandeya_purana_hindi#page/n210/mode/1up) and [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa 5.1](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/1), the name of 7 of continents (dweep) on which Priyavrata's sons ruled are as follow:

1. Jambudweep
2. Plakshdweep
3. Shalmalidweep
4. Kushdweep
5. Kraunchdweep
6. Shakdweep
7. Pushkardweep.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know by what means they are renamed in modern theory, but I can only give you the names of the 7 continents which are accepted as per Shastras.

> Siddhānta-śiromaṇi:
>
> bhūmer ardhaṁ kṣāra-sindhor udak-sthaṁ 
>  jambu-dvīpaṁ prāhur
>   ācārya-varyāḥ
>  ardhe ’nyasmin dvīpa-ṣaṭkasya yāmye
>   kṣāra-kṣīrādy-ambudhīnāṁ niveśaḥ
>  śākaṁ tataḥ śālmalam atra
>   kauśaṁ
>  krauñcaṁ ca gomedaka-puṣkare ca
>  dvayor dvayor antaram
>   ekam ekaṁ
>  samudrayor dvīpam udāharanti
>  
>  The seven islands
>   (dvīpas) are known as Jambu, Śāka, Śālmalī, Kuśa, Krauñca, Gomeda, (or
>   Plakṣa) and Puṣkara. The planets are called dvīpas. Outer space is
>   like an ocean of air. Just as there are islands in the watery ocean,
>   these planets in the ocean of space are called dvīpas, or islands in
>   outer space. There are nine khaṇḍas, known as Bhārata, Kinnara, Hari,
>   Kuru, Hiraṇmaya, Ramyaka, Ilāvṛta, Bhadrāśva and Ketumāla. These are
>   different parts of Jambudvīpa. A valley between two mountains is
>   called a khaṇḍa or varṣa.

Although I personally accept the fact that planets are called dvipas. My personal interpretation is that Earth is a dvipa, but other planets, sun and moon included are grahas. Earth is not a graha. They say that there are 7 liquid bodies surrounding each dvipa, and each body is made up of either milk, salty water, honey etc. (I forgot the others). Since the earth is surrounded by salty water, I consider it to be one dvipa. Hence I cannot convey any basis on which the modern names are given.

Comment: So you mean to say this Universe is floating?

Comment: Earth is not this universe alone. This must be understood. Our universe is unfathomable. And on top of that there are more universes. Each singular universe has these 7 divisions and subdivisions. Its utterly beyond human comprehension.

Comment: That must be the reason why "7" stands out in spirituality. From 7 Chakras to 7 Rishis - 7 gates to Vaikuntha.

Comment: Yes there verily is. I too have wondered about it.

Comment: Only a supreme Lord can create such wonderful Cosmic manifestation. Even if we souls are separated from him by Maya, still he is staying connected with us by the means of creation hiding in this Cosmos symbolically.

Comment: The Lord is not hiding. The Lord is everywhere. We need to get rid of Ahamkara and Vasanas and develop a yearning for the Lord.